# Given a RNG algorithm and a series of numbers is it possible to determine what seed would produce the series?

Tags: algorithm, math, random

The code is in Objective C but it should be understandable if you look it over even if you don't know Objective C. Basically its a RNG object, you instantiate a new instance, set the seed if you want and start grabbing random numbers.

So is it possible to backtrack a given series of numbers to determine the seed used to generate the numbers? I'm guessing any given algorithm can't generate just any random set of numbers though, or can it?

Say I do the following:

```
rng.seed = 1024;
for (int i=1; i<11; i++)
    DLog(@"%lu", [rng randomBetween:0 and:10]);
```

Which gives me the sequence `10, 10, 8, 10, 2, 10, 9, 9, 7, 4`. Is there some method or algorithm I could use, given the sequence, to get the number 1024? I know thats the valid sequence for the seen 1024, but what is I just make up a sequence... `10, 1, 9, 6, 3, 9, 10, 3, 5, 2`. Is there a way to know if that is a valid sequence for this algorithm and if so what the seed is?

RNG.h:

```
@interface RNG : NSObject
@property (assign) unsigned long seed;
- (unsigned long)random;
- (long)randomBetween: (long)min and: (long)max;
@end
```

RNG.m:

```
#define A 16807         /* a relatively prime number -- also M div Q */
#define M 2147483647L   /* 0xFFFFFFFF / 2 */
#define Q 127773L       /* M div A */
#define R 2836          /* M mod A */

@implementation RNG
@synthesize seed = _seed;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.seed = 0;
    }
    return self;
}


- (unsigned long)random {
    self.seed = A * (self.seed % Q) - R * (self.seed / Q);
    if (self.seed > M)
        return (self.seed -= M);
    else if (self.seed)
        return (self.seed);
    else
        return (self.seed = 1L);
}


- (long)randomBetween: (long)min and: (long)max {
    return ([self random] % (max - min + 1) + min);
}


- (void)seed: (unsigned long)new_seed {
    if (new_seed == 0)
        new_seed = 1;
    while (new_seed > M)
        new_seed -= M;

    self.seed = new_seed;
}
@end
```

Comment: What is the seed's range? How long is the series you have? From [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), if you have 2^32 possible seeds, if you have less then ~9 numbers in your array, it is guaranteed to have "collisions" (Simple example: A list of size 1 of numbers in range [0,9], if you have 9 possible seeds, there are 2 seeds at least that gives the same "list")

Comment: @amit - The range is a an `unsigned long`... a lot of possibilities. I'm not worried about collisions at all, if there are two or more seeds that fit the sequence, I just need the 1st one found.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a "Linear congruential generator", see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator" ?

These offer no good cryptographic security, so yes, it should be possible to compute a seed that produces the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

the code you post is basically the same as the [openbsd srandom](https://banu.com/blog/42/openbsd-bug-in-the-random-function/) - it's a linear congruential generator that is implemented to avoid rounding (which is why it contains `Q`).

[here is a paper on how to crack such a generator](http://www.reteam.org/papers/e59.pdf), but it expects the full output (not the "between" value) to be available.

i guess you should be able to extend the approach in the paper to work with "between" using arithmetic modulo the range (presumably you would need more samples).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to create an array (or disk file) that has the first value returned by your chosen algorithm for each seed.  Then just crank through the ones that match the first value looking for a longer match.  In fact, a database table would be great - gdbm or bsddb or sqlite come to mind.

This sounds to me like one of those "It's computable, but..." problems.  IOW, it can be done, but it's not especially pretty.

Comment: I'm hoping to get an algorithm I can turn in to a function to add to my class so databases are out. Brute force through each seed *would* work but that would be exceeding slow to the point of useless.

Answer (score 0):

Given a sequence s0,s1,s2,...,s(M-1) in a finite field F generated by a map H:F-->F by the iteration s(k+1)=H(s(k)), you can find the suffix x(-1) such that H(x(-1))=x0. This is called as the local inversion of H at s0. If the iteration extends the sequence to a periodic sequence then the inverse s(-1) is clearly unique and if the period is N, s(N)=s0 hence s(-1)=x(N-1). The problem of local inversion is nontrivial in practical situations because M<<N and a the period is usually expoenential in log|F| the bit length of the field size. To find s(-1) you need to find the Linear Complexity (LC) of the sequence and its minimal polynomial. The period turns out to be the order of the minimal polynomial over F. I have shown application of Local Inversion of maps to Cryptanalysis in the paper arxiv.org/abs/2207.03247v2 for both symmetric and pubic key cryptography.

Comment: Of course to find the seed of the PRNG you need to use the map of the PRNG is black box mode. Hence this method is called Black Box Cryptanalysis.